# Firebase Storage with firebase nuxt module gives Cannot read property 'delete' of undefined after deleting the file

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, nuxt.js, firebase-storage

I am using [Firebase Nuxt Module](https://firebase.nuxtjs.org/) to use firebase in my project which is running in SPA mode (No Server Side Rendering) with target static, the problem is it does delete the file then gives me the Error: `Cannot read property 'delete' of undefined` so the rest of the async function doesn't complete:

```js
async deleteFunction () {
try {
        this.deleteLoading = true;

        await this.$fire.storage
          .ref("CVs/")
          .child(this.$store.state.auth.user.uid)
          .delete();

        await this.$fire.firestore
          .collection("users")
          .doc(this.$store.state.auth.user.uid)
          .update({
            cv: this.$fire.firestore.FieldValue.delete(),
          });

        this.cvLink = null;

        this.deleteLoading = false;

        this.$notifier.showMessage({
          color: "success",
          content: "Current CV Deleted Successfully",
        });
      } catch (err) {
        this.$notifier.showMessage({
          color: "red",
          content: err,
        });

        this.deleteLoading = false;
      }
    },

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved: Discovered that the error was from the firestore delete because I had to use $fireModule instead of $fire